How should I deal with Google’s harsh treatment of my app?
A few weeks ago I submitted a new app to Google Play for review. A week later they rejected it for a pretty trivial reason, citing a screen that came up blank when there was no information to display. I added a placeholder and resubmitted.
Another week went by, then another rejection. This time the complaint was that our app asks for your name during signup, and we forgot to check “name” in the data safety form. A valid complaint, but also an easy mistake to make and one not done with any malicious intent.
I corrected it and resubmitted. This time they swiftly rejected again citing unspecified “In App Experience” issues. No explanation or screenshot. Worse, they suspended our app and threatened to close our account if we made another mistake.
I’m floored by this behavior and don’t know how to respond. I can no longer submit app updates or make any changes to my app. Why did they suspend my app? What do they expect me to do next?
This is an important app being developed by a large company to support a hardware product. It will be a disaster for us if our Android app isn’t available when our hardware goes on sale.
We submitted an iOS version of the same app, it was approved in 20 minutes.
I know this isn’t strictly a programming question but modern programmers have to deal with problems like this if we want to get our work done. I don’t like it, I’d rather discuss algorithms and languages and so forth, but this is the reality.
Thanks,
Frank

As a small company developer myself, it may get frustrating sometimes. However, you need to inform your company and stakeholders to allocate more than enough time for this process. Let's be honest here, PlayStore is a big ecosystem and reviewers probably have more than enough work load. They will not release your app instantly just because you are in rush.
Google PlayStore is usually way more easier to deal with in terms of app release process. The difference is, Apple AppStore review usually flag your app for the existing issues after some releases not in the first one.
Seems like you made some issues one after another and the reviewers flagged it as 'not caring' or 'irresponsible' developer submissions. Check the email associated with the PlayStore account. There will be a link to appeal the suspension or if it is for one app, you can request a review from the PlayStore dashboard.
Make sure to go through this guide when preparing your app for review.
You can check review request link here as shown in this screenshot:

Also if you Google, there is a contact form to ask question and clarifications to PlayStore directly.

Google not only didn't respond to my appeal, but they actually closed my developer account. I'm so confused. I've been releasing Android apps on behalf of customers since 2010. I've never seen Google treat anyone this way.
